# Oracle SQL - error when using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
select i.sicil_no,
       m.adi,
       m.soyadi,
       i.net_tutar,
       i.odeme_tarihi 
  from ibrmt050 i,
       mismt301 m 
where (i.sicil_no=m.sicil_no and 
       odeme_turu='36'       and 
       odeme_tarihi between '01/01/2012' and '30/06/2012')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(i.odeme_tarihi,'MM') ,
         To_CHAR(i.odeme_tarihi,'YYYY') 
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(i.odeme_tarihi,'YYYY') ,
         TO_CHAR(i.odeme_tarihi,'MM');
```

I want to list per by month this query but it gives error.

> "not a GROUP BY expression"

what am I supposed to do ?

Comment: What do you want to aggregate per month / what is your input and expected output? Please provide example data.

Comment: Search for `oracle not a group by expression` here on SO. There are a lot of questions concerning this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm

> **Restrictions on the Select List** 
>  The select list is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> If you also specify a group_by_clause in this statement, then this
>   select list can contain only the following types of expressions:
>
> - Constants
> - Aggregate functions and the functions USER, UID, and SYSDATE
> - Expressions identical to those in the group_by_clause. If the    group_by_clause is in a subquery, then the GROUP BY columns of the
>     subquery must match the select list of the outer query. Any columns
>     in the select list of the subquery that are not needed by the GROUP
>     BY operation are ignored without error.
> - Expressions involving the preceding expressions that evaluate to the    same value for all rows in a group

The select statements of your query contains the following columns:

```
select i.sicil_no,
       m.adi,
       m.soyadi,
       i.net_tutar,
       i.odeme_tarihi
```

that are not listed in the GROUP BY list, and this is a source of the error.